# Prometheus: Configure multiple label selectors for kubernetes_sd_configs

Tags: prometheus

I want to configure Prometheus with Kubernetes Service Discovery and filter pods by labels.

Unfortunately, the following way doesn't work:

```
kubernetes_sd_configs:
- role: pod
  selectors:
  - role: pod
    label: "app=MyApp"
  - role: pod
    label: "type=client"
```

I get an error:

```
"Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: duplicated selector role: pod"
```

Is it possible to configure multiple label selectors?

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify if you want to achieve "OR" or "AND" logical behaviour?
If it is OR -> then I'm not sure if it's possible.
Otherwise you could specify selector like this: "app=MyApp,type=client".
Prometheus uses kubernetes standard label selector: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors